# Silverlight 5 - .XNB File location

Tags: silverlight, xna

I'm using the Silverlight 5 Toolkit (That basically lets me do XNA in Silverlight).  The problem is that the XNB files that I'm generating from image files, are being stored in the .XAP File, instead of letting me just load the XNB files from the webserver.  This will become a problem when I started having a ton of images.  Is there any way for me to force it to -not- load the xnb files into the XAP file, and to instead look in directories on the web server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure why not. Keep in mind XNB files are XNA compiled files. In order to create these they must be compiled somewhere somehow, but the good this is you can create a Content project that only contains your textures, sounds, etc.

#### Process

1. HttpWebRequest to download the XNB files from your webserver

   - This will return a stream.
2. Texture2D.FromStream() to create a Texture2D from the image you downloaded

Comment: Thankyou for answering :)  I currently have a content project in the same solution as the silverlight project.  Is that the reason why its packing the XNA files into the XAP file?  Should I create a separate solution with just the content project?  OR turn off some setting that will stop it from stuffing it in the XAP file?

Comment: It really depends what you want to test. If I were to test without an internet connection (or a weak internet connection at a coffee shop) then I would reference the Content project. If I wanted to test the downloading to textures and what not I would not reference the Content Project. Either way I would have the Content project as a separate project.

Comment: That actually doesn't help.  The Silverlight Toolkit Texture2D does not have a FromStream method.

Comment: Your not supposed to be using the toolkit. Your supposed to be using the Texture2D in XNA. Do a project called Silverlight and XNA